# How do I find which users have asked the most questions?

Tags: discussion, statistics

On a particular Stack Exchange? I remember there being some site that could allow me to do that, but I don't remember where it was.

Comment: Do you mean http://data.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I tried that but I couldn't find the buttons that showed it

Comment: Well, there's [this link](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) that shows you *everything*!

Comment: Same question but across all the SE sites: [Who asked the most number of questions on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284601/178179)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/48922/finds-the-top-100-question-askers) on https://data.stackexchange.com/ shows the top 100 users with the most questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using raw SQL in [offline dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198915/159916), Joachim's query  (`OwnerUserId as [User Link]`)  wouldn't automatically create a link to the user URL.

Instead, use this query[image]:

```sql
declare @limit int=100;

select

    top(@limit)

    count(*)'Questions Asked',

    OwnerUserId,

    (select DisplayName from Users where Id=OwnerUserId)'Display Name',

    'https://stackoverflow.com/users/'+cast(OwnerUserId as varchar(100))'Text Link'

from Posts
where PostTypeId=1
group by OwnerUserId
order by 1 desc;
```